# Save image to SharedPreferences

Tags: java, mobile, sharedpreferences

I need to save this cropped image in sharedPreferences. The image will be an application wallpaper

```
       public void onChoseFiles() {
            CropImage.activity().start(MainActivity.this);
    
        }
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            ActivityResult result = getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mImageUri = result.getUri();
                myImg.setImageURI(mImageUri);
            } else if (resultCode == CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception e = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Possible Error is :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the Uri to the Shared Preferences as String :

Then you can implement :

```
    private static String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
    private static String KEY = "wallpaperObject";

    public void saveData(Uri yourUri) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY, yourUri.toString());
        editor.apply();
    }
```

The access should be possible by :

```
   public Uri loadData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String text = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY, "");
        if (!text.isEmpty()) {
            return Uri.parse(text);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Not stored");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In your implementation it could look like :

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            ActivityResult result = getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mImageUri = result.getUri();
                myImg.setImageURI(mImageUri);
                saveData(mImageUri);
            } else if (resultCode == CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception e = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Possible Error is :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private static String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
    private static String KEY = "wallpaperObject";

       public void saveData(Uri yourUri) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY, yourUri.toString());
        editor.apply();
    }


    public Uri loadData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String text = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY, "");
        if (!text.isEmpty()) {
            return Uri.parse(text);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Not stored");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I would also add to your Activity onCreate() to load the last set image:

```
if(loadData() != null){
myImg.setImageURI(mImageUri);
}
```

Comment: How do I put both methods in "onActivityResult"?

Comment: @Whiskey I edited the answer... You put the methods into your activity class.

Comment: There was an error loading "Uri so = new Gson (). FromJson (text, Uri.class);"

Comment: @Whiskey Copy the upper code I corrected it :)

Comment: @Whiskey OK I saw u got it by ur self

Comment: When I add a new image, does it replace the previous one?

Comment: Yes it will. If you want to have multiple you need to store the Strings in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I used it like this and it worked. what am i missing?

It works like this !!!

onCreate

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String mImageUri = preferences.getString("image", null);
    if (mImageUri != null) {
        myImg.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mImageUri));
    } else {
        myImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.print);
    }
```

And

```
  public void saveData(Uri yourUri) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(mImageUri));
        editor.commit();
    }
```